# How to count non-null elements in an iterable?

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension, idioms

I'm looking for a better/more Pythonic solution for the following snippet

```
count = sum(1 for e in iterable if e)
```

Comment: whats wrong or 'unpythonic' with your way?

Comment: Generator expressions are Pythonic. Do you just mean shorter?

Comment: OP, be aware exactly what is and is not non-null, in Python. For example `sum(1 for e in [False, 0, '', [], (), [''], (''), [False], (False,), None] if e)` actually evaluates to 3 instead of 0, because bizarrely the nested sequences `[['']]`, `[[False]]`, `[(False,)]` count as non-null, yet `[('')]` doesn't, [! Anyway in general, the code you give is fine and adequate to the task, if we're guaranteed the list is flat.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
len(list(filter(None, iterable)))
```

Using `None` as the predicate for `filter` just says to use the truthiness of the items. (maybe clearer would be `len(list(filter(bool, iterable)))`)

Comment: +1 This is nice and fast (about 8x faster than the generator expression on my computer). `bool` seems to be just slightly slower than `None`

Comment: Fast solution, but the O(N) extra memory is a minus. My list usually has 1000000 elements so using 1MB memory only to count non-zero elements it's not that efficient. Plus I don't think you timed the gc to reclaim the list generated by filter.

Comment: That's just a complicated way to len(list(iterable)).

Comment: This will exclude False as well as None. Despite the OP's stated problem, the title implies counting non-null, not non-null-equivalents. I came here looking for something like `filter(None, mylist)` that would still count False as not null. (I removed the downvote because this solution will work for the stated problem, just not what the title implied the problem is.)

Comment: Using `len(filter(None, iterable))` gives me an error `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`. Am I missing on something here?

Comment: @Priya You need to typecast the `filter` to `list` (or similar type) - `len(list(filter(None, iterable)))` would work

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I can't think of a better way to do it than what you've got.

Well, I guess people could argue about "better," but I think you're unlikely to find anything shorter, simpler, and clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(not not e for e in iterable)
```

Comment: Wow. This answer is old enough that `bool(e)` did not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Most Pythonic is to write a small auxiliary function and put it in your trusty "utilities" module (or submodule of appropriate package, when you have enough;-):

```
import itertools as it

def count(iterable):
  """Return number of items in iterable."""
  return sum(1 for _ in iterable)

def count_conditional(iterable, predicate=None):
  """Return number of items in iterable that satisfy the predicate."""
  return count(it.ifilter(predicate, iterable))
```

Exactly *how* you choose to implement these utilities is less important (you could choose at any time to recode some of them in Cython, for example, if some profiling on an application using the utilities shows it's useful): the key thing is having them as your own useful library of utility functions, with names and calling patterns *you* like, to make your all-important *application level* code clearer, more readable, and more concise that if you stuffed it full of inlined contortions!-)

Comment: "calling patterns [that] you like": non-author code readers may be expected to know what (for example) `sum(map(bool, iterable))` does without asking on SO or looking up TFM ... having to find a definition somewhere else breaks the reading flow.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the title is somewhat dissonant with the question. If we would insist on the title, i.e. counting non-null elements, the OP's solution could be modified to:

```
count = sum(1 for e in iterable if e is not None)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the fastest, but maybe handy for code-golf

```
sum(map(bool, iterable))
```

Comment: Only in Python 2.x - in Python 3, map returns a generator, not a list.

Comment: Also you can use imap from itertools.

Comment: This won't work if the iterator contains any values that evaluate to false (like an empty string, zero, `False`, an empty list...)

Comment: @Quartz, well like most answers here, it is equivalent to the snippet provided in the question body, rather than the heading :)

Comment: @Quartz, JohnLaRooy, I corrected the title to *"sum non-null elements"* and added a caveat comment, I think that fixes everything?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to see whether the iterable is not empty, then this would probably help:

```
def is_iterable_empty(it):
    try:
        iter(it).next()
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The other answers will take O(N) time to complete (and some take O(N) memory; good eye, John!).  This function takes O(1) time.  If you really need the length, then the other answers will help you more.

Comment: Ummm well (1) this would be shorter: `is_iterable_empty = lambda it: not any(it)` (2) Doesn't this consume the first element if the iterable is not empty and is an iterator?

Comment: Actually, your solution with the `any` function won't actually do the same thing in all cases.  If the iterator just returns `False` boolean objects (or empty lists, etc.), then your lambda would give a false positive.  I'm sure this code could be shortened, but I like giving expanded code for demonstrations.

As for consuming the first object, yes, it will, but all of the solutions here will consume at least one element (most consume all).  There isn't a good way to get around this, but as long as it's documented, then everything should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Propably the most Pythonic way is to write code that does not need count function.

Usually fastest is to write the style of functions that you are best with and continue to refine your style.

**Write Once Read Often** code.

By the way your code does not do what your title says! To count not 0 elements is not simple considering rounding errors in floating numbers, that False is 0..

If you have not floating point values in list, this could do it:

```
def nonzero(seq):
  return (item for item in seq if item!=0) 

seq = [None,'', 0, 'a', 3,[0], False] 
print seq,'has',len(list(nonzero(seq))),'non-zeroes' 

print 'Filter result',len(filter(None, seq))

"""Output:
[None, '', 0, 'a', 3, [0], False] has 5 non-zeroes
Filter result 3
"""
```

Comment: No that's not, it's just a convoluted way of saying `len(list(item for item in seq if item!=0))`. That's actually **less Pythonic**. There's no need for `nonzero(seq)` to construct the throwaway intermediate list when all we want to do is count 1's for whether an item is nonzero or not. Doing that inside a generator expression means we don't need to construct an intermediate list, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with O(n) runtime and O(1) additional memory:

```
count = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, imap(lambda v: v>0, iterable))
```

Hope that helps!