# Fastest way to filter json string in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a json structure like

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": {
        "d": "3"
    }
}
```

What I want is to only keep the 1st level of the json, i.e. remove if 1st level's value is not a string, so I have a program like

```
import json

s = ''' {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": {
        "d": "3"
    } } '''

data = json.loads(s) 
ret = {}

for k, v in data.items():
    if (isinstance(v, basestring)):
        ret[k] = v

print json.dumps(ret)
```

Since I need to process huge amount of json string like that, I am looking for if any fastest way or more elegant way to do the same thing in Python

Comment: be careful when you use json string verbatim inside a Python string literal. Use raw-string literal `r''` to avoid interpolating backslashes inside json.

Comment: if the question is about performance then you should provide a basic benchmark and determine how fast is fast enough in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
ret = {k: v for k, v in json.loads(s).iteritems() if isinstance(v, basestring)}
```

The `dict.iteritems()` call here prevents a full list being built first.

If your JSON input is truly huge, consider switching to an iterative JSON parser like [`ijson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/), and parse your JSON with an event-driven interface:

```
import ijson

ret = {}
key = None

with open(some_large_jsonfile) as json_file:
    for prefix, type, value in ijson.parse(json_file):
        if prefix and not '.' in prefix and type == 'string':
            # only top-level string values
            ret[prefix] = value
```

but it could be a good idea to process the key-value pairs right there and then rather than build up a full dictionary.

Comment: my json is not huge, but I have many lines of json need to process.

Comment: @Ryan: dict comprehension might be slower than an explicit loop (here's an [example where a generator expression (related concept) is slower than an explicit for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23318776/4279)). If an individual json object is small then it is not clear what would be faster a loop that uses `.iteritems()` or `.items()` (all items have to be created anyway, same logic as `xrange()` vs `range()`). Without a benchmark it is hard to say. `unicode` could be used instead of `basestring`. Do you mean that you have many small json objects (one per line) e.g., like tweet stream?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, my json is around 4K in size (average), anyway, I will do the benchmark first. Thanks.